# Google maps info window

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi i have been using this code to show multiple location on a google map and also dropping pins on each location.

```
var mylocation = new google.maps.LatLng(52.520816, 13.410186);

var neighborhoods = [
new google.maps.LatLng(52.511467, 13.447179),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.549061, 13.422975),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.497622, 13.396110),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.517683, 13.394393)
];

var markers = [];
var map;

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
center: mylocation
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
mapOptions);
drop();
}

function drop(){
for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) 
{
markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
position: neighborhoods[i],
map: map,
}));
}

}
```

what i want is to show info window on all the pins showing their respective lats and lngs

Thanks

Comment: Would you like some ketchup or mayonnaise with that, sir?

Comment: Your code is irreverent here. Your question should be: "How do I show an info window with the Google api". Better yet would be to just google it : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function drop()
{
 for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) 
 {
   var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
   position: neighborhoods[i],
   map: map,
   });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:marker.getPosition()});
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need is in the Google maps documentation, in the [InfoWindow section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows), where they show this example:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h2>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
    'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
    'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335 km (208 mi) '+
    'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450 km '+
    '(280 mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
    'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
    'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
    'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
    'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
    'Heritage Site.</p>'+
    '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
    'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> (last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Uluru (Ayers Rock)"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```